# Rails querying by belongs_to relationship method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Location which many models use to store geographic-type information. I am using https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder to filter results based on location. My issue is, how do I call the .near method on the belongs_to location. Example:

I have a User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Location:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I would normally join Location and query from there:

```
User.joins(:location).where('locations.country = ""')
```

The issue is, I can not pass a hash or a string, I need to call a method from Location, something like

```
# Instead of calling .near on User, I need to on Location
User.joins(:location).near('Omaha, NE, US', 20)
```

I am not sure how I can do this, or if it is possible. Thanks

Comment: Look into using scopes http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Not sure if this works for you, but try this: `User.joins(:location).merge(Location.near('Omaha, NE, US', 20))`

Comment: @fivedigit That seemed to do the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can query on `Location` with a join on `User`, even without a relation defined from `Location` to `User`, and get the id of the users :

```
users_id = Location.join('INNER JOIN users ON users.location_id = locations.id').near('Omaha, NE, US', 20).pluck('users.id')
users = User.find(users_id)
```